# Javascript: Force a change in select if value is selected as something else

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to change the value of my select option to change back to value of 74 here. I need the user to (after selecting not 74) force the option to be back to 74.

```
var shippingProvince = document.getElementById("shipping:region_id");
shippingProvince.addEventListener('change',
    function () {
        if (shippingProvince.value != 74) {
            alert("This is not 74");
            shippingProvince.value == 74;
        }
         else {
            shippingProvince.value == 74;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: take a look of http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp in select tag, javascript value property does not work. You need to use selectIndex

Comment: Fot starters, use just one "=" when assigning a value: shippingProvince.value = 74;.. Btw, why not just disable the select if you don't want the user to be able to change it?

Comment: @DineshPatra no, do not take a look at w3schools; the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) is a much better resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making an equality check (`==`), rather than assignment (`=`).

```
shippingProvince.value = 74;
```